# Error while Storing data into list with class

Tags: c#, list, class

//Storing data into list with class

Step 1 : I  created a class called Temprecord.cs

```
    // Created a Class 
Using namespace testwork
  {
    Public Class RecordDetail{
      public string Field1 { get; set; }
      public string Field2 { get; set; }
      public string Field3 { get; set; }
      public string Field4 { get; set; }
      public string Field5 { get; set; }
      public string Field6 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

step 2 In a different file (work.cs) I am creating a list using the above class and adding value to it.

```
    {
    //some code 
    List<RecordDetail> Temprecord = new List<RecordDetail>();
```

I observe an error when I try to write the following code 
         Temprecord tempdata = new Temprecord();

**"Error    10**    The type or namespace name 'Temprecord' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
    /*tempdata.Field1 = "Name";
    tempdata.Field2 = "City";
    tempdata.Field3 = "Country";
    tempdata.Field4 = "PhNo";
    tempdata.Field5 = "email"
    tempdata.Field6 = "Status"

    Temprecord.Add(tempdata);*/
    }
```

I have included the required references but continue to observe the error.

Comment: Temprecord is a file name, not a class. The class is `RecordDetail`. `RecordDetail tempdata = new RecordDetail();` (you are doing it correct, when creating a list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct then you have a namespace `testwork` which has two classes `RecordDetail` and `work` and you want to add data to it.

It can be done in many ways. One of them would be

```
  List<RecordDetail> Temprecord = new List<RecordDetail>(){

            new RecordDetail(){Field1="SomeValue",Field2="SomeValue"......},
             new RecordDetail(){Field1="SomeValue",Field2="SomeValue"...},
              new RecordDetail(){Field1="SomeValue",Field2="SomeValue"...},
               new RecordDetail(){Field1="SomeValue",Field2="SomeValue"...}
    };
```

What you are doing is creating instance of `Temprecord` which is wrong you dont have any such class.

Answer (score 0):

> I created a class called Temprecord.cs

No, you did not. You created a class called `RecordDetail`. Use that class. And rename your file accordingly if you want to stay sane.

Answer (score 0):

`List<RecordDetail> recordDetails = new List<RecordDetail>();` means `recordDetails` contains multiple `RecordDetail` class objects.

```
e.g
RecordDetail objdata1=new RecordDetail ();
RecordDetail objdata1=new RecordDetail ();
RecordDetail objdata3=new RecordDetail ();
RecordDetail objdata4=new RecordDetail ();
recordDetails .Add(objdata1);
recordDetails .Add(objdata2);
recordDetails .Add(objdata3) etc..
```

So,

```
List<RecordDetail> recordDetails = new List<RecordDetail>()
RecordDetail objdata=new RecordDetail ();

objdata.Field2 = "City";
objdata.Field3 = "Country";
objdata.Field4 = "PhNo";
objdata.Field5 = "email"
objdata.Field6 = "Status"

recordDetails.Add(objdata);
```